# Sandboxed webpage in SvelteKit causes SOP error

Tags: cors, sandbox, sveltekit, same-origin-policy

I have a SvelteKit website where users can upload JS code that other users then can run in their web browsers. To make it secure, the webpage running the user provided JS code has a Content-Security Policy that limits what the JS code may do, and I've almost got this to work.

My problem is that I want to use the `sandbox` directive without the `allow-same-origin` value, because I don't want the user provided JS code to be able to read/change the data other users have in their `localStorage` on my website. But when I remove that value, the webpage gets its own unique/`null` origin, and that gives me a Same-Origin Policy error that looks like this for each JS file the webpage tries to fetch:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://my-website.com/_app/immutable/entry/start.8e96ba46.js. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 200.

Now I'm stuck.

1. Is there a way to add CORS headers to the responses for these static files in SvelteKit?
2. Is it possible to somehow "inline" the requested JS files on this specific webpage that is sent back, so the web browser doesn't need to send the HTTP requests for the JS files at all?
3. Is there another way to achieve what I want?

---

The code causing the cross-domain requests is the standard SvelteKit code on the page:

```html
<script>
    {
        __sveltekit_i1n7th = {
            base: new URL("../..", location).pathname.slice(0, -1),
            env: {}
        };

        const element = document.currentScript.parentElement;

        const data = [null,null];

        // These trigger other imports in turn.
        Promise.all([
            import("../../_app/immutable/entry/start.ec215fac.js"),
            import("../../_app/immutable/entry/app.4c6d3256.js")
        ]).then(([kit, app]) => {
            kit.start(app, element, {
                node_ids: [0, 16],
                data,
                form: null,
                error: null
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```

---

Related reading:

- The "official" SvelteKit solution for now seems to be to add a proxy server ([source](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/2060#issuecomment-1109831845))

Comment: You wrote: _a Same-Origin Policy error that looks like this for each JS file the webpage tries to fetch_. Do you really need to configure CORS for those JS resources? What's triggering CORS? How is the page loading those scripts? Are they modules? Or are you using subresource integrity, perhaps?

Comment: If you really need to configure CORS for those JS resources, I'm guessing they don't require credentialed access (e.g. via requests that carry cookies), right? If so, you can configure CORS and allow all origins with `*`. Allowing `null` is strongly discouraged (for security reasons).

Comment: @jub0bs, If I understand right, it's the standard SvelteKit code that triggers the imports. I've included the code for that in my question post now. And you're right; no credentials needed to access those. And I haven't found a way to add CORS headers to responses for static resources in SvelteKit (hooks don't run for them). Using a proxy for adding those seems like the only way, and I don't find adding one very tempting.

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty, but setting up my own [custom server](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-node#custom-server)/proxy and adding the CORS header there solved it for me:

**server.js**

```js
import { handler } from '../build/handler.js'
import http from 'node:http'

const server = http.createServer(function(request, response){
    
    if(request.url?.startsWith(`/_app/immutable/`)){
        response.setHeader(
            `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`,
            `*`,
        )
    }
    
    // Not sure if I'm using handler() correct like this,
    // but it seems to work for me.
    handler(request, response)
    
})

server.listen(3000)
```

Feels like one shouldn't need to do something this complicated to do something as easy as adding headers to a response though.